# Flipclock countdown does not appear on pageload on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flipclock

The countdown is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, in IE, I am not sure why the countdown does not appear when the page is loaded in IE. I

One suggestion I attempted was to change the format of the date entered (which is the commented out date) which did not work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date("August 31, 2020 12:00 AM PST"); //Month Days, Year HH:MM:SS
    //var date = new Date('2020-08-31T11:00:00.000Z');
    var now = new Date();
    var diff = (date.getTime()/1000) - (now.getTime()/1000);
    
    if(diff <= 0){
        var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(
            0, {
                countdown: true,
                clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                  /*alert("Time is Up!!");*/
                }
            }
        });
    } else{ 
        var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(
            diff, {
                countdown: true,
                clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                 /**/
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Another suggestion was to fix the -webkit- which when reviewing look fine to me.

Here is the css:

```
/* Get the bourbon mixin from http://bourbon.io */
/* Reset */
.flip-clock-wrapper * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff; }

.flip-clock-wrapper a:hover {
  color: #fff; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  list-style: none; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:before,
.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1; }

/* Main */
.flip-clock-wrapper {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
}

.flip-clock-meridium {
  background: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 !important;
  font-size: 36px !important; }

.flip-clock-meridium a { color: #313333; }

.flip-clock-wrapper {
/*  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 660px;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper:before,
.flip-clock-wrapper:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.flip-clock-wrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}

/* Skeleton */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 87px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #337ab7;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 87px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li:first-child {
  z-index: 2; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 200px;
  -moz-perspective: 200px;
  perspective: 200px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  cursor: default !important; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 80px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  outline: 1px solid transparent; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  top: 0; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #337ab7;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 70px; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up div.inn {
  top: 0; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down div.inn {
  bottom: 0; }

/* PLAY */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before {
  z-index: 3; }

.flip-clock-wrapper .flip {   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active {
  -webkit-animation: asd 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: asd 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  animation: asd 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  z-index: 5; }

.flip-clock-divider {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px; }

.flip-clock-divider:first-child {
  width: 0; }

.flip-clock-dot {
  display: block;
  background: #337ab7;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(20, 48, 72, 0.5);
  left: 5px; }

.flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  right: -86px;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: none; }

.flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label {
  right: -88px; }
  
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label {
        margin-right: 315px;
        margin-top: 135px;
    }
    
    .flip-clock-divider.minutes{
        margin-bottom: 36px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 780px) {
    
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn {
        font-size: 64px;
    }
    
    .flip-clock-wrapper ul {
        width: 48px;
    }
    
}

.flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label {
  right: -91px; }

.flip-clock-dot.top {
  top: 30px; }

.flip-clock-dot.bottom {
  bottom: 30px; }

@-webkit-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  20% {
    z-index: 4; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@-moz-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  20% {
    z-index: 4; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@-o-keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  20% {
    z-index: 4; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

@keyframes asd {
  0% {
    z-index: 2; }

  20% {
    z-index: 4; }

  100% {
    z-index: 4; } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both;
  animation: turn 0.5s 0.5s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@-o-keyframes turn {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

@keyframes turn {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: turn2 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: turn2 0.5s linear both;
  animation: turn2 0.5s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@-moz-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@-o-keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

@keyframes turn2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg); }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg); } }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul li.flip-clock-active {
  z-index: 3; }

/* SHADOW */
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .up .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, #337ab7));
  background: linear, top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  animation: show 0.5s linear both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .up .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, #337ab7));
  background: linear, top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, #337ab7 100%;
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  -moz-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both; }

/*DOWN*/
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-before .down .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #337ab7), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background: linear, top, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  -webkit-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  -moz-animation: show 0.5s linear both;
  animation: show 0.5s linear both; }

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.play li.flip-clock-active .down .shadow {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #337ab7), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background: linear, top, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%);
  background: linear, to bottom, #337ab7 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100%;
  -webkit-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  -moz-animation: hide 0.5s 0.3s linear both;
  animation: hide 0.5s 0.2s linear both; }

@-webkit-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-moz-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-o-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0; }

  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-moz-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-o-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1; }

  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }
    
.center{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.timer {
    zoom: 0.5;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
}

.flip-clock {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

/*===================
Change panels to color
=====================*/
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(2) li a div div.inn,
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(3) li a div div.inn
{
    background : #337ab7;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(5) li a div div.inn,
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(6) li a div div.inn
{
    background : #337ab7;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(8) li a div div.inn,
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(9) li a div div.inn
{
    background : #337ab7;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(10) li a div div.inn,
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(11) li a div div.inn
{
    background : #337ab7;
}

.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(11) li a div div.inn,
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip:nth-child(12) li a div div.inn
{
    background : #337ab7;
}

/*=====================
Add Responsiveness
=======================*/
// 
// ------------------------- FlipClock
// 
$clock-flip-font-size: 120px
$clock-flip-border-radius: 8px
$clock-digit-gap: 20px
$clock-dot-size: 20px

$clock-height: ($clock-flip-font-size * 1.2)
$clock-flip-width: ($clock-flip-font-size * 0.8)
$clock-flip-margin: ($clock-digit-gap / 2)
$clock-flip-section-width: (2 * ($clock-flip-width + 2 * $clock-flip-margin))

$clock-flip-bg: #607D8B
$clock-flip-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
$clock-flip-font-color: #F44336
$clock-flip-font-shadow: 0 1px 2px #337ab7

.countdown-wrapper
  left: 50%
  position: absolute
  top: 50%
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul
  height: $clock-height
  margin: 0 $clock-flip-margin
  width: $clock-flip-width
  box-shadow: $clock-flip-shadow

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li
  line-height: $clock-height

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn
  background-color: $clock-flip-bg
  color: $clock-flip-font-color
  font-size: $clock-flip-font-size
  text-shadow: $clock-flip-font-shadow

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul,
.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn
  border-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.down
  border-bottom-left-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius
  border-bottom-right-radius: $clock-flip-border-radius

.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div.up:after
  top: (($clock-height / 2) - 1px)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot.top
  top: ($clock-height / 2 - $clock-flip-font-size * 0.2 - $clock-dot-size / 2)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot.bottom
  top: ($clock-height / 2 + $clock-flip-font-size * 0.2 - $clock-dot-size / 2)

.countdown .flip-clock-dot
  height: $clock-dot-size
  left: $clock-dot-size
  width: $clock-dot-size
  background: $clock-flip-bg

.countdown .flip-clock-divider
  height: $clock-height
  width: ($clock-dot-size * 3)
  &:first-child
    width: 0

.countdown .flip-clock-divider.seconds .flip-clock-label,
.countdown .flip-clock-divider.minutes .flip-clock-label
  right: -1 * $clock-flip-section-width

.countdown .flip-clock-divider .flip-clock-label
  color: $clock-flip-font-color
  font-size: $clock-flip-font-size / 4
  width: 2 * $clock-flip-width + 4 * $clock-flip-margin
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: @j08691: IE11 but I was able to resolve the issue. Thank you for your help

Comment: @RobertoFlores From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You can post your solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.